# OptaPlanner how to reject moves on Heuristic Part

Tags: drools, optaplanner, heuristics

I am working on a project and I have to reject some moves from being tested.
I have done that on local search with "isMoveDoable" but ConstructionHeuristics maybe needs different configuration. I don't want to delete Heuristics part because it's very effective.

```
  <!-- Power tweaked optimization algorithms configuration -->
  <constructionHeuristic> 
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
  </constructionHeuristic>

  <localSearch>
    <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>

    <moveListFactory>
      <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.optional.move.CloudBusChangeMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
    </moveListFactory>

    <!--<unionMoveSelector>-->
      <!--<changeMoveSelector/>-->
      <!--<swapMoveSelector/>-->
      <!--<pillarChangeMoveSelector/>-->
      <!--<pillarSwapMoveSelector/>-->
    <!--</unionMoveSelector>-->

    <!--<acceptor>-->
        <!--<entityTabuRatio>0.1</entityTabuRatio>-->
    <!--</acceptor>-->
    <!--<forager>-->
      <!--<acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>-->
    <!--</forager>-->
  </localSearch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for **move filtering** (see docs). Don't use `isDoable()` to filter out moves that aren't interesting to evaluate.

I am not a big fan of move filtering however - it's often the wrong solution for the question on "how can we improve solution quality". It's a pain to have to configurate it on every move selector. Instead, use optaplanner-benchmark to determine if the score calculation speed is fine (above 1000 at the very least!). If it isn't, find the bottleneck in your constraints. If it is, add coarse-grained moves to escape from local optima faster.

Comment: I understand what you saying but I have to reject some moves as I said before but I dont want to delete them because its important their score for my solution. What do you sugest?